# Vertical align elements of different heights with top/bottom margin

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have been trying to vertical align links in a list, where all but one of the links has background color/border (to look like a button).

Even though the code on this fiddle works, it doesn't respect the reduced height of that link (the Sign In link).

```css
html body,
ul,
div,
li,
a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.inner {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: grey;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(http://static1.tme.eu/pics/icons/no-image-placeholder-big.png);
  background-size: 150px 20px;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
}
.right-nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 46px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
ul li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 46px;
}
.icon-user:before {
  content: "\e745";
}
a.button {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f38060;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #f38060;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <ul class="left">
    <li>
      <a class="logo" href="/"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="right-nav">
    <a class="mobile-menu right" href="#"><span class="icon-menu"></span>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="button" href="#" style="height: 60px;">Sign In
        <span class="icon-user"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6er3aguk/

What I would like to achieve is basically to have some sort of top/bottom margin on that Sign In link, so it doesn't stick to the top and bottom of the surrounding div.

Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

Comment: My $.02: The way your code renders looks better (and more modern) than the solution below. Also, since the rest of the links in the navbar are full-height, shouldn't that one be, too?

Comment: Thanks. The solution below does work, but you raise a good point. I wouldn't mind if all links had like `height: 80%` or a smaller height than the parent div. However, I couldn't achieve that. Do you know of an alternative way of doing that? edit: I guess what I'm trying to avoid is just the last button to touch the parent div, because it doesn't look nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would create the effect that you're looking for.

This will vertically center the links, clear the parent properly. And irregardless of the browsers font-setting, at it's minimum width it will stop contracting with 15px of spacing between each element and the sides of the container if the window is smaller than the nav, instead of overlapping or moving to new lines.

This also completely avoids the use of floats and `display: table` hacks.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6er3aguk/4/)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html body, ul, div, li, a {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    left: 172.5px;
    right: 0;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: grey;
}
ul {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
}
ul:before {
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
}
ul:before,
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul li a {
    font-size: 12pt;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 10px 7.5px;
}
.right li:last-child {
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.right a {
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.right a:hover {
    background: #888;
}
.icon-user:before {
    content:"\e745";
}
a.button {
    background: #f38060;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
a.button:hover {
    background: #f98666;
}
a.logo {
    background-image: url(//placehold.it/150x20);
    background-size: 150px 20px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
    <ul class="left">
        <li><a class="logo" href="/"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="right">
        <a class="mobile-menu" href="#">
            <span class="icon-menu"></span>
        </a>
       <ul>
            <li><a href="/#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li>
                <a class="button" href="#">Sign In
                    <span class="icon-user"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the preferred style by putting the `Sign In` text and the `span` inside a `div` and applying the same styles you did for `a.button` to that div.

```css
html body,
ul,
div,
li,
a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.inner {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: grey;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(http://static1.tme.eu/pics/icons/no-image-placeholder-big.png);
  background-size: 150px 20px;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
}
.right-nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
ul {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 46px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
ul li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 46px;
}
.icon-user:before {
  content: "\e745";
}
#signin {
  max-height: 60px;
  background-color: #f38060;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #f38060;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <ul class="left">
    <li>
      <a class="logo" href="/"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="right-nav">
    <a class="mobile-menu right" href="#"><span class="icon-menu"></span>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="button" href="#" style="
height: 60px;
                                          ">
          <div id="signin">Sign In<span class="icon-user"></span>
          </div>

        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```